# What's happening with the heart when you push your rectum really hard?

Tags: blood-pressure, valsalva-maneuver

I've noticed in myself, and am wondering what is going n, because when I push hard if I'm sitting on my chair - A thick Vein on my neck has a pretty big pulse, like it controls blood flow, and could be dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Pushing (when you go to the bathroom) can be associated with stimulating the Vagus nerve. This can lead to a rapid drop in blood pressure and heart rate and may result in fainting. If you loose consciousness from this, it is known as a vasovagal syncope episode. The act of bearing down in this way is known as the Valsalva maneuver (which does actually have a purpose in cardiology*). This information came from [HealthGrades.com](https://www.healthgrades.com/conditions/vasovagal-attack), similar information can be found on the Mayo Clinic's website (I didn't include it because it was a bit chopped-up).

From what I have read, bearing down isn't good for your head if you have a known brain aneurysm. Hence it is recommended that if you have a known aneurysm in your head, that you take laxatives (especially before surgery).  If you would like more information on this, please visit the [Stroke Association site](http://www.strokeassociation.org/STROKEORG/AboutStroke/TypesofStroke/HemorrhagicBleeds/What-You-Should-Know-About-Cerebral-Aneurysms_UCM_310103_Article.jsp#.V727zCgrLIU).

*The Valsalva Maneuver is used as a treatment for a variety of conditions as well as a diagnostic tool for them (listed below). The maneuver's mechanism occurs when a person bears down and holds their breath. When this happens, pressure in the chest cavity increases and venous return decreases. This results in a very rapid decrease in heart rate and systolic blood pressure. It is because of this rapid decrease both in HR and BP that can cause dizziness or syncope not only when purposely preforming this maneuver but also when you are on the toilet.

The Valsalva Maneuver is used to treat SVT (SupraVentricular Tachycardia), traditional tachycardia (high heart rate), tachypnea (high respiratory rate), and A-Fib (Atrial Fibrillation) among others. It also has a wide range of diagnostic uses - not relegated to the cardiovascular or respiratory system - such as a pinched nerve, certain types of hernia, brain deformity etc.

Additional information on the Valsalva Maneuver can be found [here](http://www.ehealthstar.com/test/valsalva-maneuver) and [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6565684). Please note that both of these links have a much better description of the exact mechanism of this maneuver than I could provide. Also, this [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtGg9j8yJTc) link is very awesome! However, it was accidentally cut off at the end and there is no second part to it.

Hope this information is helpful to you, if you have additional questions regarding this, let me know and I will do my best to answer them.

Comment: A vasovagal syncope episode might be a better reference of what is described, related to straining. Also, the etiology of subarachnoid hemorrhage is more complex, and the study referenced in the CBS coverage was in Stroke: Journal of the American Heart Association, published May 5, 2011. It was specific to those individuals already diagnosed with an aneurysm and ways to reduce their rupture risk.

Comment: @Dorothy Yeah, I know. Hence my notation that that wasn't really the best reference that I could have. And I am quite sure that straining that hard cannot possibly good for one's head. Regardless, I will make some slight changes to my answer.

Comment: as you do, suggest he add the tags 'blood pressure' and 'syncope' and, perhaps, remove 'cardiology'

Comment: @Dorothy I did so and considered adding neurology but then did not.

Comment: The vagus nerve has interesting effects on the heart. For example, some people who have atrial fibrillation can terminate episodes of it with the Valsalva maneuver, while for others it can trigger an episode.

Comment: @CareyGregory I know! I wanted so badly to go into detail about that but since that wasn't the question I had to use my best self control... :)

Comment: There is definitely no rule that says your answer can't go beyond the narrow specifics of the question. That's often what makes for really good answers.

Comment: @CareyGregory Hmm... I now prepare to make a lengthy answer

Comment: But when I give a big push (without holding any breath at all not none) a big pulse goes through a vein at the top of my chest in ex. the left shoulder socket hole thing like under your neck area. Is it dangerous? At times I have did repetitious pushes possibly up to a hundred times a day, thankly have basically stopped it though.

Comment: @FriendlyPerson44 No, it's not dangerous.